# How to add loading image for iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to know how may I add a Loader Gif Image for iFrame. The loader Image will load until the iFrame Src is load fully. I preferred Javascript but I didn't able to do it

Comment: What did you try? You can use javascript to display the loading graphic and use the `onload` event of the iframe to then clear the graphic.

Comment: It's better to use AJAX call to load the contents into DIV, using `.load()` from jQuery function, if you can avoid using iframe.

Comment: Hi, I can't avoid using iFrame. I am loading a third party website within my website. And I want to load a Loading Image until the iFrame website has been loaded properly. Can you please write the code? I don't know JS

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I create a div tag with a image inside or as the background image and absolutely position it over the iFrame.

When the IFrame is loading it is visible display:block and when has finished hide it display:none.

Listen to the onload event of the IFrame to check for completion.